I am trying to upload a .vhdx file from my portable hard drive into a virtual machine using windows 10
As mentioned above, I am trying to import a .vhdx file from my portable hard drive into a virtual machine using Hyper-V. I have looked online and can't seem to find anything related to this whatsoever. When I start the conversion, I get an error that says "Failed to convert the virtual disk. The system failed to convert (Insert Path)". My thought process is to do this so I have a backup of this in case the computer ever goes down, I'll always have a "clean" backup of this somewhere on a virtual machine that I can access when needed.
I tried doing this through Hyper-V Quick Create. When I selected an Operating system, I chose Local Installation Source, and when I had to choose a hard disk file, I selected my .vhdx file from my portable hard drive and clicked create. Once it gets to about 3% I get the error code "Failed to convert the virtual disk. The system failed to convert (Insert Path)". I am expecting this to create the virtual machine with the .vhdx file in there so that I have it as a clean backup option for whenever I'll need it for future use.

Yes! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! Now we are trying to add dummy files to the virtual machine into the C: Drive so that the actual computer could access those files if necessary. At first, when we tested to see if our file would be accessible on our actual computer, it didn't show up. Trying this ended up breaking the virtual machine where we couldn't start it anymore. We get the error "The application encountered while attempting to change the state of (Name of VM)". Any ideas of a workaround this?

No worries, I figured out a workaround for this. You just go into Task manager and shut down anything Hyper-V related that is open and then it fixes itself. Thank you for your help.
